# The initial value problem $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x^{\frac{3}{2}}(t),~x(0)=0$ has

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The initial value problem
$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x^{\frac{3}{2}}(t),~x(0)=0$ has

A) Unique solution

B) Two solution

C) Infinitely many solution

D) None of the above

$\textbf{My try}$

As we know for $x=0$ is the one solution, let's see for other solutions

$\int x^{-\frac{3}{2}} dx~=~\int dt$

After some simplification

$\sqrt{x}=-\dfrac{2}{t+c}$

After applying $x(0)=0$ we got
$-\dfrac{2}{c}=0$.

Which means option C is wrong. And option A is correct.
But according to answer key, answer is $\textbf{infinite number of solutions}$. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure of the initial condition?

Comment: Your ODE function is differentiable and thus locally Lipschitz in $x=0$, so the usual uniqeness claim applies. You would get more comfortable in the theoretical setup if you extended the function to negative arguments, like in $\dot x=x\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: As the others commented (and as you showed), this initial value problem has only one solution. If the question were asking about the differential equation without the initial condition, then it would have an infinite family of solutions.